# How to restrict proxied apps based on application auth logic

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, rewrite

I have a vhost with mod proxy that redirects fine, but I’d like to add to it.

Here’s my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.domaine.local

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /subsonic/ http://serv2.domaine.local/subsonic/
    ProxyPassReverse /subsonic/ http://serv2.domaine.local/subsonic/

    ProxyPass /owncloud/ http://serv3.domaine.local/owncloud/
    ProxyPassReverse /owncloud/ http://serv3.domaine.local/owncloud/

    ProxyPass / http://serv1.domaine.local/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://serv1.domaine.local/

</VirtualHost>
```

In serv1 I have my own php/mysql/ldap application, which authenticates my users. One of my rules is : 1 user can access 0,1 or N apps.

So i would like that for example :

- a non authenticated user can have just this part of the reverse proxy vhost:

  ```
  ProxyPass / http://serv1.domaine.local/                              
  ProxyPassReverse / http://serv1.domaine.local/
  ```
- a user that is allowed access to only one app ("subsonic") would have access to:

  ```
  ProxyPass / http://serv1.domaine.local/                              
  ProxyPassReverse / http://serv1.domaine.local/
  ```

  AND

  ```
  ProxyPass /subsonic/ http://serv2.domaine.local/subsonic/
  ProxyPassReverse /subsonic/ http://serv2.domaine.local/subsonic/
  ```
- a "all access" user can access all defined proxies

I don't know how to do that, perhaps i could put for example a variable `$_SESSION['authtothisapp'] = true ;` in my php application, but how to say to apache `if $_SESSION['authtothisapp'] = true` then allow access to a given proxied app?

Comment: The way your formatted this question is very confusing. I suggest you approve the pending edit to improve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

On a global proxy level I've done it using session cookies like this:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  SetEnvIf Cookie "authtoken=myCookie" let_me_in
  Allow from env=let_me_in
</Proxy>
```

You may be able to restrict access to individual directories based on cookies using explicit URLS in the Proxy config like this:

```
 <Proxy http://example.com/foo/*>
```

But I have not personally tested that option.